# magento installation error - reset.php is missing

Tags: magento, themes

Any idea about the below error

`Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/inhyshoper/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/default/etc/reset.php' (include_path='/home/inhyshoper/public_html/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')` in `/public_html/includes/src/EM_Themeframework_Model_Observer.php on line 287`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clear admin cache and apply the theme in change design section

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like permission issue. put 777 permission to your theme folder, it may works.
Please let me know if not work.

Answer (score 0):

Magento version?
Which theme installed

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: version : 1.9.3.19